# Can't type certain square brackets in Visual Studio 2010 + Resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper, square-bracket

In certain cases typing an opening square bracket results in nothing at all. In particular when I want to type them on a variable in the right side of assignment expression:

```
arr[i] = arr
```

So I cant type, for example:

```
arr[i] = arr[9]
```

It has something to do with Resharper. However, turning of autocomplete and stuff doesn't seem to solve it. Anyone familiar with this problem?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it with VS2010 and R#5.1. Does it depend on the array type?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had the same issue the first time I insalled Resharper.
Look under Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard to what is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> (equals to <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> since I suppose you work on an AZERTY keyboard). Easiest way of doing is by just entering it as a new shortcut.

Remove or rebind the shortcut that comes up and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you! I had this issue in Visual Studio 2010 when doing C++. I just thought my IDE was drunk. It was bound to "Align assignments", so it only gave me issues on lines containing a "=". It wasn't aligning anything, anyway...

Answer (score 0):

I had the almost same issue in Visual Studio Express 2012. I couldn't write theese -> } <-.
(Same problem as you, @hazard)

After reading @Bart's answer, I saw that Ctrl+Alt+0 was connected to something called "View.ViewCode". So I removed that shortcut and it worked.

What's weird though, is that I COULD write }s during the first few hours I used VS2012 after installing it.