# Python Visual Studio Code square brackets are not recognized

Tags: python, list, visual-studio-code

I have the following problem in Visual Studio Code 2019 where Anaconda python 3.7.4 64-bit intepretator is used. I am trying to create a list using the following python code:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
```

However instead of creating the list compiler initializes the tuple since the following code

```
type(my_list)
```

returns (class 'tuple') which should be the case if I use round brackets or no brackets at all like in the following code

```
my_list = 1, 2, 3
```

My guess is that Visual Code by some reasons ignores the fact that I am providing the square brackets. Similar problem has been discussed in this post [Can't type certain square brackets in Visual Studio 2010 + Resharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324691/cant-type-certain-square-brackets-in-visual-studio-2010-resharper).

Please help me to figure out the problem related to the Visual Studio ignorance of square brackets.

Will be very greatfull for help!

Comment: Is there anything else in between `my_list = [1, 2, 3]` and `type(my_list)`? Your code might have unwittingly changed the `type` in between.  Also did you try another Python interpreter?

Comment: There is no additional code in between and in other redactors it works fine. I have not been trying to use alternative interpreters.

Comment: Regional/Language setting is English on your OS and VSCode? Try the stock Python interpreter if you could and see the problem persists.  Other than these suggestions I'm afraid I can't be helpful as I can't produce the same results.

Comment: Thank you very much for suggestion! I will make these steps and response if it helps.

Comment: Can you provide a complete code snippet of what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

I face the similar (or the same?) issue when running `ptpython` inside console in *the editor area*. When I press `[`, `]`, `<`, `>` and some other symbols I can't enter them. Also if I paste a snippet with those symbols, they are ignored and didn't appear in the code.

When I hold `ALT` while typing `[`, `]`, `<`, `>` then it helps to type.

I found this inconvenient and switch to regular console (not in editor area). There I don't have such issue.

BTW, check that you can type the symbols in other filetypes. If so, then check hotkeys whether something bound to `[` and `]`.